# vitest Error - React refresh preamble was not loaded. Something is wrong

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

while I'm using a new project its works fine .
When I try to config with my existing project vitest throws this error

- Faild suitcase Error :  React refresh preamble was not loaded. Something is wrong.
- vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [ react()],
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true
    }
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: ['./src/test/setupTests.js'],
    testMatch: ['./src/test/**/*.test.jsx'],
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
    }

  }
})
```

- setupTests.js

```
import { expect, afterEach } from 'vitest'
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'
import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers'

expect.extend(matchers)

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup()
})
```

- Auth.test.js

```
import {fireEvent, render , screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import { describe, it } from 'vitest'
import Auth from '../components/auth/Auth'


describe('App ', () => {
  it("renders headline", () => {
    render(<Auth />)
    const btn = screen.getByTestId("sumbitButton")
    expect(btn).toBeInTheDocument()
  })


})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with Vitest latest version. You can down version to  "vitest": "^0.33.0". It works for me. Maybe something went wrong with from 0.34.0 version onwards.

If using @vitejs/plugin-react instead of @vitejs/plugin-react-swc it works fine for the latest Vitest version

Comment: Using "^0.33.0" worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was React's fast refresh plugin.

It's possible to run the tests by disabling it and changing the following configuration:

```
plugins: [ react({
  fastRefresh: false
})],
```

Since this configuration is shared with dev server, it will also impact it's behavior so it's far from optimal.

Will be looking for alternative solutions.